# Groovy returns error when creating xlsx file

Tags: groovy

i have a groovy code to create xlsx file.
The code is adapted from java.
it returns error when executing.
Can someone help me please.

The error returned is:

```
No expression for the array constructor call at line: 11 column: 25. File: Script2.groovy @ line 11, column 25. data.put("1", new Object[] {""+ID+""}); ^
```

here is the code:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


def ID = "str123"
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();         
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("City");      
Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();
data.put("1", new Object[] {""+ID+""});             
Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
int rownum = 0;
for (String key : keyset)
{
Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
Object [] objArr = data.get(key);
int cellnum = 0;
for (Object obj : objArr)
{
Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
if(obj instanceof String)
cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
else if(obj instanceof Integer)
cell.setCellValue((Integer)obj);
}
}
try 
{
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\temp\\demo.xlsx"));
workbook.write(out);
out.close();            
System.out.println("success");           
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
e.printStackTrace();    
}
```

Comment: There is a great [Spreadsheet Builder](https://spreadsheet.dsl.builders/) in the Groovy ecosystem. Less verbose and less error-prone way to create XLS(X) documents using DSL-like syntax in Groovy.

Answer (score 1):

this line:

```
data.put("1", new Object[] {""+ID+""});
```

is written in one of the few ways Java is incompatible with Groovy... using {} for static initialization fails in Groovy, as it looks like you're passing a Closure.

Off the top of my head, try:

```
data.put("1", [ID] as Object[] );  // array with one entry, the String
```

looks like you want an array with a string in it.

Comment: The later one is correct for OPs code; yet from a Groovy point of view most of that is rather verbose/java-ish.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, then i tried to add spreadsheet-builder-groovy-2.2.1.jar in soapui/bin/ext and even with this it's not working for me with spreadsheet builder.

Comment: @tainghong does my 2nd above change the error you're getting?  It should resolve the one you posted.

Comment: @billijamesdev i tried your second code and i get this message: Type org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPivotCache not present java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.

Comment: @tainghong this might be relevant https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/I-am-not-able-to-open-xlsx-file-created-with-groovy-code/td-p/214156   If not, i suggest a new question, as we've solved your original.